# Finding the tangent to a graph without a point but with the gradient of tangent

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a math question that I can't solve. It is as follows:

Find the coordinates on the graph of the point where $y = \sqrt{2 + 1}$ where the gradient of the tangent to the graph is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's first find:

$$\frac{\text{d}\text{y}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{2x+1}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+1}}\tag1$$

So, for what $x$ is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+1}}=\frac{1}{3}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\dots\tag2$$